# Creating a 300 dpi PDF context

Tags: ios, cocoa, pdf, postscript

I am trying to create a multipage PDF document that I intent to print from an OSX app.

The hard part is finding a decent tutorial to understand the whole process. One has to use paranormal abilities to guess how it works or ask here :)

This is the point.

Every time a PDF context is created I see this line

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);
```

If I understood correctly, given that a PostScript point is 1/72 inch then

```
612 x 792 points = 8.5 x 11 inch = 215.9 mm x 279.4 = US Letter paper size.
```

But I see a problem here, this page will be printed at 72 dpi, right? Pretty much low resolution. How do I create something like 300 dpi?, just increase the number of points proportionally, or in that case create a context of 2550x3300 points?

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Another point is this: I am creating a context of the whole page. How do I know the are I can really print? Is all area printable in a PDF document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is not printed at 72 dpi, that's merely the co-ordinate system. PDF files are (usually) vector based, and even if not can contain images of arbitrary resolution, the 'P' in PDF stands for Portable, so you don't generally need to worry about resolution.

The printable area of a PDF is that which is contained in the MediaBox, or the BleedBox, as limited by the CropBox, again in general you don't need to worry about these.

Comment: Right. You can use floating point numbers inside the valid range for width and height to "exactly" position anything you want. The OP seems to be mixing up "pixels" with "points".

Comment: I don't get it. Suppose I want to place a picture inside the pdf that is 2000x2000 pixels at 300 dpi. The context is fixed at 612 x 792 and I am working with postscript points inside. Now suppose I want to put that picture in the middle of that context on a box of 400x400 points. Then I use Quartz to draw that image inside the box. If I understood correctly, Quartz will scale the image to put it inside the box. Now 2000x2000 pixels are inside 400x400pt area. If this is right, 400pt each point at 1/72 inch, will give me a size of 5.5 inches at 72dpi. If I print it at 300 dpi I will have a ...

Comment: ... (cont)... crappy image, right? I write books and all these years I have created 300 dpi PDFs that are called "print quality" to book printers and when I export my texts I always specify the resolution and I can definitively create low and high resolutions PDF. Always using 612x792 sounds to me that I cannot ever increase the resolution... or I did not understand that.

Comment: @RubberDuck A point is not a pixel. I don't see where 72dpi comes from. 612x792 is just the *dimensions*, not the resolution. Also, for efficiency, image rendering is usually done with a *reverse sampling* technique, so reducing resolution (when rendering the pdf to a lower-resolution device) should lose a uniformly distributed selection of source samples. This part is in the 1982 Warnock/Wyatt paper which is the basis of the Adobe image model for both pdf and postscript.

Comment: if a postscript point is 1/72 inch, then 72 pt = one inch. If one inch has 72 points then it is 72 points per inch. Points per inch = resolution = density of points per inch, isn't it?

Comment: Basically, no. The co-ordinate system is 72 points to the inch, but, unlike pixels, your co-ordinates need not be integer. So you can position graphics at (for instance) x=0.5 y=0.5. There is no 'points per inch', points are a metric, like inches, or centimetres. There are 72 points in an inch in the same way there are 100 centimetres in a metre. You seem to be under the impression that PDF is a bitmap format, it isn't. There are no pixels in a PDF file (embedded images are better described in terms of samples) and there is no resolution for a PDF file.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to write a bit more on the second part of your question (because I think the first part has been answered sufficiently by KenS. But I see too much possibility for confusion in your second question and wanted to elaborate.

As KenS says, the "P" in PDF stands for "Portable" which is another way of saying that PDF was designed to be device independent. That is why there is a coordinate system that works with 72 points which is then "converted" at print time to whatever resolution the actual printing device works at (or viewing device for that matter as we might just as well be talking about seeing a PDF on screen or on an iPad).

The second consequence for that is that PDF by itself doesn't know nor does it care what your printer can do. When you create a page with the call you showed in your code example, you're creating a PDF file that has a page with a MediaBox set to US Letter size. As far as PDF is concerned, you can draw content on that whole page area (and outside of it for that matter).

This does not say anything on whether that content will actually be printable. If you have a printer that can print page-wide, you may be able to get away with putting content right unto the edge of the page. If your printer requires half an inch gripping area where it can't print, some of your content may be clipped by the printer. If you're sending your PDF to a professional graphic arts workflow, some of the content may actually need to "bleed" (extend outside the page) so that cutting your page to final size doesn't cause problems.

The PDF file by itself doesn't care - it's device agnostic. It's your decision where to put content on the page. You may:

a) decide to use some other code to get the actual printable area for a particular printer and format your content accordingly.

b) decide to create a PDF that will print correctly on "most" decent printers.

Doing b) certainly follows the spirit of the PDF specification more than doing a), but sometimes a) is just easier :-)

Comment: OK, but what I don't understand is this. When I export texts to PDF, lets say using Pages, I can choose (on Adobe Distiller) the resolution I want to export my images. Lets say I choose 300 dpi, like I did a number of times on distiller. What happens then? Suppose I have a 2000x2000 pixels image that is drawn on a 400x400pt inside that 612x792pt context. The 2000x2000 image, if printed at 300 dpi, will give me a high quality printing that will measure 6.66 inches. If I place that image inside the 400x400pt box what will happen? Will many pixels will be discarded?

Comment: ... (cont)... if the box is 400 pt wide and 1 pt is 1/72in, then that box can be printed without degradation at 5.55 inch. So, if that PDF is to create the page of a book where the image will have to have 6.66, the image will be scaled beyond the limit and lose resolution... or I did not get it...

Comment: @RubberDuck This would be better as a new question IMO.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it - it's really simply :) Your image is placed in a certain space on the page - say 5 by 5 inch. Your image has a number of pixels in both directions. The number of pixels per inch is what is important for print quality (ppi) - that's the number that has to be over 150 or 300 (for example) depending on the printing process.

Answer (score 3):

Ken's and David's answers are both correct. This answer intends to address (what I consider to be) the *deeper level* of confusion underlying the question. PDF (and my beloved Postscript) are *vector graphics* formats, not -- I repeat -- **not** like an image (byte-map) format at all. This distinction extends down to the very *atoms* of the PDF universe, points.

A point in PDF is like a point in Geometry class. It merely designates a location on the plane. It does not cover any area. It is infinitely small.

*But -- you say -- PDF can contain embedded images! So they have to be combined into the same level of detail to coexist in the same file!*

No. PDF maintains embedded images, *embeddedly*. The image data exists in its own local context where the placement and location on the page (the larger, common context) is governed by a vector-geometry tool, an Affine (bi-linear) transform.

Now, there is a sense in which points do have *resolution*. Since a point is expressed as a computer word, it must be representable within the range of a computer word. So we have a range of about 4 billion for a 32bit integer, and a much broader range but with less precision for a 32bit floating-point (normalized mantissa-exponent form). So the numbers themselves *bottom out* if you go low or small enough. I believe Adobe's interpreters claim 8 decimal digits of precision for a floating-point value, whereas the standard C library only claims 6. So you can't really deal with images of dimensions *50 million by 50 million*, because the vector machinery breaks down.

But none of that need concern you for any normal usage. It only comes up if you're trying to something crazy like a deep fractal zoom, but you probably wouldn't do that with pdf either.